# Encoding files with Java

Tags: java, file, encoding, hex

I am making an app in Java with NetBeans and I face a problem with file encoding.

ΤHe purpose of the application is to create the necessary files (project files) for another software (LedshowYQ 2016). LedshowYQ 2016 is used with LED Signs.

The problem that I face is with txs files. These files are used for sending text on the sign. Apart from the desired text, they hold the format and color information.

In the link below you can download a txs file.
[txs file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzk19gn4r5xzv3g/a621a82257859807ef6bbfea5703ec0a.txs?dl=0)

When I open the file in notpad, I get this:

```
-8 1 3 1
-7 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0
-9 2 0 0 2 0 1
rvs
X       StyleNameNormal text
SizeDoubleFontNameTahomaColorclWhiteUnicode Size  -9 2 0 0 2 0 2
rvs
E       StyleNameLeftStandardOptionsrvpaoDoNotWantReturns Tabs   -9 2 0 0 2 0 4
rvs
    -9 0 0 0 0 0 7
0 1 0 8 0 0
D u m m y   T e x t )
```

However, when I open it in Sublime Text, I get this:

```
2d38 2031 2033 2031 0d0a 2d37 2030 202d
3120 3020 3020 3020 3020 300d 0a2d 3920
3220 3020 3020 3220 3020 310d 0a72 7673
0d0a 5800 0000 0e01 0953 7479 6c65 4e61
6d65 060b 4e6f 726d 616c 2074 6578 740a
5369 7a65 446f 7562 6c65 0218 0846 6f6e
744e 616d 6506 0654 6168 6f6d 6105 436f
6c6f 7207 0763 6c57 6869 7465 0755 6e69
636f 6465 0904 5369 7a65 020c 0000 2d39
2032 2030 2030 2032 2030 2032 0d0a 7276
730d 0a45 0000 000e 0109 5374 796c 654e
616d 6506 044c 6566 7408 5374 616e 6461
7264 0807 4f70 7469 6f6e 730b 1572 7670
616f 446f 4e6f 7457 616e 7452 6574 7572
6e73 0004 5461 6273 0e00 0000 2d39 2032
2030 2030 2032 2030 2034 0d0a 7276 730d
0a02 0000 000e 002d 3920 3020 3020 3020
3020 3020 370d 0a30 2031 2030 2038 2030
2030 0d0a 4400 7500 6d00 6d00 7900 2000
5400 6500 7800 7400 2920
```

From the above I understand that the file is in hex format.
So, my initial solution was to add the hex code which is not going to be altered, in a String variable, get the text from textfield, convert it to hexadecimal, add it to the String variable and write it to a new txs file.

```
private String baseText = "contains the unchanged part of the code";
private String readedText = textField1Bar.getText();
private String hexTextConv = String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, readedText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
hexTextConv += "2920";

String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mytext.txs";
        File myTxsFile = new File(filePath);
        try{
            myTxsFile.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try{
            FileWriter sfwTxs = new FileWriter(myTxsFile);

            try(BufferedWriter sfbwTxs = new BufferedWriter(sfwTxs)){
                    sfbwTxs.write(hexTextConv);
                    sfbwTxs.flush();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }catch(IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But when I opened it in Ledshow, it is not displayed...

Then, I thought of making a keylogger in a way. I got the text from textfield, read all characters, and with a switch statment I converted each character to a hexadecimal value. All those values where added to the initial String variable and written to the txs file.

Still, the result is the same. It cannot be displayed in Ledshow.

I used all the availiable options of StandardChaset, with no luck.

Then I thought maybe the format of the file is different from what is seen in sublime text and I converted the hexcode to byte before writing it to file.

```
byte[] b = hexTextConv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
//
//
//
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
   fos.write(b);
}catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The result was the same!:) In order to feed my curiosity I opened the created file in Sublime text and the output was the same hexadecimal values as before.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?
I am really out of ideas and I cannot move forward from this point.

Comment: Just want to point out that long posts are usually good; they indicate research and effort (assuming most of that is actual text and not a 1000 line code dump or dummy text to bypass the system quality checks).

Comment: There's no such thing as "the file is in hex format". It's just that sublime somehow decided that the file isn't pure text and shows you the hex dump of the file instead, as if it was a binary file. That's probably because that file contains some control characters in addition to the text content. Notepad simply doesn't support this and just tries to show everything as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file starts with single-byte ASCII encoding, but afer "rvs\r\n" it switches to something like two-byte UTF-16LE encoding (0x00 bytes), that contains ASCII text again.

No wonder that Sublime Text assumes binary data, and does a hex dump, displaying every byte as two digits in base 16 (0-9A-F). `2d` then is the '-' character, `31` the '1' character and so on.

It also means you must read the file as binary data.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mytext.txs");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

The parsing then becomes a bit ugly, but as you did, you can translate text strings into byte sequences as:

```
string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);  
string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was wondering, should I divide the text strings into two parts due to different ecodings (1. from the begining of the file until "rvs\r\n" and 2. from  "rvs\r\n" until the end of the file) in order to write them to the file correctly?